# filtering a linq query, based on the object created from each element in the linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query, that's filtering a file list.  It's doing exactly what I need it to do, however I'm concerned about the objects I'm creating in the where statement.
Is there a more efficient way to reuse the object I've created for each of the comparisons I need to make ?

```cs
void Main()
{
    string sourceDirectory = @"G:\Citect-Overhaul";

    var filelist = from fl in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.tsv")
                   where (new Citect_File(fl)).Dataset == "crusher"
                       && (new Citect_File(fl)).Citect_DataDate == "20190901"
                       && (new Citect_File(fl)).Short_Citect_Dataset == "mill"
                   select new Citect_File(fl);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you have to create it only once for every file.

```
var filelist = Directory
    .GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.tsv")
    .Select(fl => new Citect_File(fl))
    .Where(cf => cf.Dataset == "crusher"
              && cf.Citect_DataDate == "20190901"
              && cf.Short_Citect_Dataset == "mill");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var filelist = from q in
                           from fl in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.tsv")
                           select new Citect_File(fl)
                       where q.Dataset == "crusher"
                           && q.Citect_DataDate == "20190901"
                           && q.Short_Citect_Dataset == "mill"
                       select q;
        var filelist2 = from fl in Citect_File((Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.tsv"))
                        where fl.Dataset == "crusher"
                           && fl.Citect_DataDate == "20190901"
                           && fl.Short_Citect_Dataset == "mill"
                       select fl;
```